# Generate a wildcard term from a list of similar strings

Tags: c#, .net

What I'm trying to do is create an app which generates a Solr query from a list of strings.  I have long lists of hostnames that I need to shrink down as much as possible.  Here's an example of what I need to accomplish.

Given the following dataset:

```
AAABBBCCC-1234
AAABBBCBC-1334
AAABBCCBC-1324
QEUVWISKPWW1114
QEUSPISGPWW2114
QEUSPISTPWW1614
```

The output should look like this:

```
AAABB?C?C-1??4
QEU??IS?PWW???4
```

To start with, I've tried using `.GroupBy(item.SubString(0,5)`, but the issue is there's a little too much variance to be accurate.  Right now I'm attempting to come up with a way to loop through the list to find the highest number of like sequential characters and group those together.  This would at least be a good starting place, and from there within the group, look for where each index of the string matches all other items within the collection, replacing it with a `?` where it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, downvotes and no comments don't help.  Before downvoting, please comment and let me know why.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you are saying "Hey, I'd like to do something, tell me how".  That's not really what this site is for.  In addition, you don't specify how to measure whether a solution meets your needs.  I can think of an algorithm that would end up with "??????????????" as the solution (it, by the way, matches what you've asked for).  What's your definition of "good enough"?  What have you tried?  What issues are you facing?

Comment: @Flydog57 - This is a really good point.  I guess the success criteria is where I'm able to group together _x_ number of strings together.  I've tried using `.GroupBy` with a list of these, but the problem there is that for one group the first 6 characters may all match, while in another, only the first 3 would be similar.  I'll try updating the question.

Comment: Pattern finding is a greedy and complex. Solvable ([1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-1-naive-pattern-searching/), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/),[3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-3-rabin-karp-algorithm/), [4](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-5-finite-automata/) etc). Consider alternatives (e.g. ip-s and their ranges). Perhaps intended operation can be done per instance/call to that host, so no pattern needed. Clarify end goal, suggest options, community will respond.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out a way to solve my problem here, but if someone has a better way of doing this, I'll gladly change the marked answer.

```
        //Variables class I created elsewhere
        Vars.hostnameInput = 
@"AAABBBCCC-1234
AAABBBCBC-1334
AAABBCCBC-1324
QEUVWISKPWW1114
QEUSPISGPWW2114
QEUSPISTPWW1614";

        //Split the string into a list
        var hostnameList = Vars.hostnameInput.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //Create groups where the first three characters match
        var groups = from item in hostnameList
            group item by item.Substring(0, 3)
            into g
            select g;

        //Iterate through each group
        foreach (var _group in groups)
        {
            var wildcard = "";
            //Order the list so that the longest string in the group is at the top
            var hostnames = _group.OrderByDescending(t => t.Length).ToList();
            bool charMatch = false;
            //Split longest string in the group into a Char array to compare to the rest in the group
            var hostnameChars = hostnames[0].ToCharArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < hostnameChars.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (var hostname in hostnames)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Check the character in each string at the same index
                        if (hostnameChars[i] == hostname[i])
                        {
                            charMatch = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            charMatch = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //If the current string is shorter, the extra characters should result in a '?'
                    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                    {
                        charMatch = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //If all characters at index i match, leave it in, if not, replace with '?'
                if (charMatch)
                {
                    wildcard += hostnameChars[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    wildcard += "?";
                }
            }
            //Add new wildcard terms to output
            Vars.solrScript += $"{wildcard}\r\n";
            foreach (var hostname in _group)
            {
                Vars.solrScript += $@"  {hostname}{Environment.NewLine}";
            }

        }
```

Output:

```
AAABB?C?C-1??4
                AAABBBCCC-1234
                AAABBBCBC-1334
                AAABBCCBC-1324
QEU??IS?PWW??14
                QEUVWISKPWW1114
                QEUSPISGPWW2114
                QEUSPISTPWW1614
```